# insert mysql_fetch_array multiple rows into a table

Tags: rows

I am extremely noobie with php. I have figured these thru tutorial. Now I am trying to finish the last part.

Here is the first part of the script:
It looks for a list of awards that is available for the movie with movid=$get_movie[id]

```
$award=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM award WHERE movid=$get_movie[id]"));
```

Then I have this to check if the list of awards is already added to the movie or not on user profile

```
$award_exists=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT award_id FROM userawards WHERE user_id=$user AND mov_id=$get_movie[id]"));
```

If the award does not exist in the user profile, add it to the user profile
else don't add.

```
if(empty($award_exists['award_id'])) { mysql_query("INSERT INTO userawards (user_id, mov_id, award_id) VALUES ($user, $get_movie[id], $award[id])") or die (mysql_error);
} else if($award['id'] !=$award_exists['award_id']){ mysql_query("INSERT INTO userawards (user_id, mov_id, award_id) VALUES ($user, $get_movie[id], $award[id])") or die (mysql_error); }  else if($award['id'] =$award_exists['award_id']){ }
```

For example, for movie 3, I am suppose to have 5 awards ready to be added to the user profile, but I am able to only insert one of the awards into the user profile.

I search around foreach and while and I have tried to implement it for the past 5 hours.. I just couldn't do it.. Can someone please help me.

Thank you so much